# Нужна ли запятая после слова "просто"?

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая после слова "просто" во фразе "Просто мы первые"? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

***Просто мы первые.***

Слово ***просто*** является частицей и не обособляется

**ПРОСТО** III. частица. Разг. 2. **Всего лишь, всего-навсего; не иначе как.** Вы п. смеётесь над нами. Всё это п. детское упрямство. Он п. не умён.